# popup dialog as input

Tags: android, popupwindow

Hey, I have a problem with implementing a popup dialog like this one in this example: http://malsandroid.blogspot.com/2010/04/list-picker-and-fading-popup-notice.html

Its working just fine if I implement the code for a editbox. The problem is, that I want to use a options menu in the app that lets the user control if he wants to use the standard keyboard in android or this popup dialog as input to the editboxes.

If i put this code directly into the main.java class it works fine as I just said ( same as code example above ):

```
hcp_entry_player_1 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.hcp_entry_player_1 );

final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a hcp");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) 
    {
        hcp_entry_player_1.setText(items[item]);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    }
});

builder.create().show();
```

To make a long story short, when I use the options menu I need to use onClickListener between different void methods. Therefor I can not call **`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`**. Ive tried to call **`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`** but it is not working. To be honest I dont realy understand the problem?.

I will type more code in case someone is interested:

```
public void setListInputMethod()
{
     for( EditText et : mEditTextList )
     {
         et.setEnabled(false);
         et.setOnClickListener(mTouchTextFieldListener);
     }
}

private OnClickListener mTouchTextFieldListener = new OnClickListener()
{
     EditText et;
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         et = (EditText)v;

         final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
         builder.setTitle("Pick a hcp");
         builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) 
            {
                et.setText(items[item]);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 return;
             }
         });
         builder.create().show(); 
     }
 };
```

This method loops all edit-texts in the app and tries to set the popup dialog as input, but its not working as described above. Realy need advice, thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getApplicationContext()`, try storing the activity itself as a static variable and using it for the context.

In your class:

```
private static Activity activity;
```

Somewhere in `onCreate()`:

```
activity = this;
```

Then do:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
```